# Appium/Python/Android: activate_app command doesn't work correctly on real device but works fine on AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, python-appium

Scenario:

1. I started Appium
2. I started appA
3. I started appB
4. I call appA back from backgound by below command:

> driver.activate_app()

This command worked on AVD devices, appA is displayed for later actions, then I bring this code to real device (same OS version) and:
at step 4, appA is brought back in only 1 second then suddenly appB is shown back over

What is the difference between AVD and real device environment?

Comment: Did you specify the device name for the real device?

What is the error message

Comment: Ofcourse, I specified the device name for the real device so it could start appA, appB.

Comment: As far to my knowledge, there should not be a different in activate_app() for avd and real device. But you may want to check on the appium log if there are any other commands call.